# MIDI and Bit Order

Tags: encoding, hex, arrays, bit-manipulation, midi

I'm stuck trying to format a MIDI Sys Ex message that a device keeps rejecting as invalid. The problem is a section of the message that involves a type of data encoding described below.

According to the manual,

the device "will encode/interpret a consecutive group of 4-bytes"

Byte #0 - b<sub>31</sub>b<sub>30</sub>b<sub>29</sub>b<sub>28</sub>b<sub>27</sub>b<sub>26</sub>b<sub>25</sub>b<sub>24</sub>

Byte #1 - b<sub>23</sub>b<sub>22</sub>b<sub>21</sub>b<sub>20</sub>b<sub>19</sub>b<sub>18</sub>b<sub>17</sub>b<sub>16</sub>

Byte #2 -   b<sub>15</sub>b<sub>14</sub>b<sub>13</sub>b<sub>12</sub>b<sub>11</sub>b<sub>10</sub>b<sub>09</sub>b<sub>08</sub>

Byte #3 -   b<sub>07</sub>b<sub>06</sub>b<sub>05</sub>b<sub>04</sub>b<sub>03</sub>b<sub>02</sub>b<sub>01</sub>b<sub>00</sub>

as the following 5 consecutive SysEx bytes:"

Byte #0 - 0   b<sub>06</sub>b<sub>05</sub>b<sub>04</sub>b<sub>03</sub>b<sub>02</sub>b<sub>01</sub>b<sub>00</sub>

Byte #1 - 0   b<sub>13</sub>b<sub>12</sub>b<sub>11</sub>b<sub>10</sub>b<sub>09</sub>b<sub>08</sub>b<sub>07</sub>

Byte #2 - 0   b<sub>20</sub>b<sub>19</sub>b<sub>18</sub>b<sub>17</sub>b<sub>16</sub>b<sub>15</sub>b<sub>14</sub>

Byte #3 - 0   b<sub>27</sub>b<sub>26</sub>b<sub>25</sub>b<sub>24</sub>b<sub>23</sub>b<sub>22</sub>b<sub>21</sub>

Byte #4 - 0   0   0   0  b<sub>31</sub>b<sub>30</sub>b<sub>29</sub>b<sub>28</sub>

*where "b" is the bit number*. Notice the bit numbering has been flipped. Which way are you supposed to read the bits? MIDI data is, by convention, reverse bit ordered (MSB=7), if that helps. Also, the manual notes that "all data types are in Motorola big-endian byte order."

Here's a description of the message I'm trying to format correctly -

"A command will allow a consecutive group of one to four bytes to be edited. When 3 or less bytes are specified the device expects the Parameter Value field to be bit ordered as if it was performing a full 32-bit (4 byte) parameter change. For example, when editing a two byte parameter, Byte #0 will occupy the bit range of b<sub>24</sub>-b<sub>31</sub>, while Byte #1 will occupy bits b<sub>16</sub>-b<sub>23</sub>. The remaining bits (b<sub>00</sub>-b<sub>15</sub>) in the parameter value field should be set to zero."

bb      Parameter Offset    -   **0**   b<sub>06</sub>b<sub>05</sub>b<sub>04</sub>b<sub>03</sub>b<sub>02</sub>b<sub>01</sub>b<sub>00</sub>

bb      Parameter Offset    -   **0**   b<sub>13</sub>b<sub>12</sub>b<sub>11</sub>b<sub>10</sub>b<sub>09</sub>b<sub>08</sub>b<sub>07</sub>

bb      Parameter Offset    -   **0**   b<sub>20</sub>b<sub>19</sub>b<sub>18</sub>b<sub>17</sub>b<sub>16</sub>b<sub>15</sub>b<sub>14</sub>

bb      Parameter Offset    -   **0**   b<sub>27</sub>b<sub>26</sub>b<sub>25</sub>b<sub>24</sub>b<sub>23</sub>b<sub>22</sub>b<sub>21</sub>

bb      Parameter Offset    -   **0   0   0   0**   b<sub>31</sub>b<sub>30</sub>b<sub>29</sub>b<sub>28</sub>

0b      Parameter Byte Size (1 to 4)

00

00

00

00

bb      Parameter Value -   **0**   b<sub>06</sub>b<sub>05</sub>b<sub>04</sub>b<sub>03</sub>b<sub>02</sub>b<sub>01</sub>b<sub>00</sub>

bb      Parameter Value -   **0**   b<sub>13</sub>b<sub>12</sub>b<sub>11</sub>b<sub>10</sub>b<sub>09</sub>b<sub>08</sub>b<sub>07</sub>

bb      Parameter Value -   **0**   b<sub>20</sub>b<sub>19</sub>b<sub>18</sub>b<sub>17</sub>b<sub>16</sub>b<sub>15</sub>b<sub>14</sub>

bb      Parameter Value -   **0**   b<sub>27</sub>b<sub>26</sub>b<sub>25</sub>b<sub>24</sub>b<sub>23</sub>b<sub>22</sub>b<sub>21</sub>

bb      Parameter Value -   **0   0   0   0**   b<sub>31</sub>b<sub>30</sub>b<sub>29</sub>b<sub>28</sub>

So, when trying to enter offset values of 15H, 16H, 17H, and 18H, with respective values of let's say 00, 01, 02, 03 respectively, how would I encode those hex values, or do I even need to encode them? If I do need to, which direction do I write the bits so the binary values are correct?

Comment: You can use <sub> </sub> to make subscripts. I changed the bit numbers into subscripts to make the question easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

When written, the order of bits in a byte is always big-endian, i.e., MSB first.
This can be confirmed by the fact that the MSB must be zero for data bytes.

---

```
Four bytes:
  15h -> 00010101
  16h -> 00010110
  17h -> 00010111
  18h -> 00011000
SysEx bytes:
         0 0011000 -> 18h
         0 0101110 -> 2eh
         0 1011000 -> 58h
         0 0101000 -> 28h
         0000 0001 -> 01h
```

```
Four bytes:
  01 -> 00000001
  02 -> 00000010
  03 -> 00000011
  04 -> 00000100
SysEx bytes:
        0 0000100 -> 04h
        0 0000110 -> 06h
        0 0001000 -> 08h
        0 0001000 -> 08h
        0000 0000 -> 00h
```

Comment: Thanks! So b31 is the MSB in this example and b00 the LSB? Are bits usually represented with such numbers?

Comment: The bit numbers *do not matter*, except for knowing how to rearrange them. If the bits were called A, B, C … or Tom, Dick and Harry, it would not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

The basic approach to this conversion is to combine the four 8-bit values into a 32-bit value and then successively move the least significant seven bits into five bytes. Here's a sample program that does what you need.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void convert(uint8_t byte0, uint8_t byte1, uint8_t byte2, uint8_t byte3, uint8_t *outBytes) {
    uint32_t inBytes = byte0 << 24 | byte1 << 16 | byte2 << 8 | byte3; //combine the input bytes into a single 32-bit value
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        outBytes[i] = inBytes & 0x7F; //Copy the least significant seven bits into the next byte in the output array
        inBytes >>= 7; //Shift right to discard the seven bits that were copied
    }
}

void printByteArray(uint8_t *byteArray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("Byte %d: %02xh\n", i, byteArray[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    uint8_t sysExBytes[5]; //Five bytes to contain the converted SysExData

    convert(0x15, 0x16, 0x17, 0x18, sysExBytes);
    printByteArray(sysExBytes);

    convert(0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, sysExBytes);
    printByteArray(sysExBytes);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Byte 0: 18h
Byte 1: 2eh
Byte 2: 58h
Byte 3: 28h
Byte 4: 01h

Byte 0: 03h
Byte 1: 04h
Byte 2: 04h
Byte 3: 00h
Byte 4: 00h
```

Comment: Thanks @SSteve. Do you think you could explain the algorithm in plain english? I'm not a programmer, and I don't really understand the syntax you're using.

Comment: I'm not going to have time this week to write up anything in depth, sorry. The essence is that you put the four eight-bit bytes together and then divide the bits up in groups of seven instead of eight.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is a bit confusing.  1 byte is 8 bits, therefore the following lines:

> Byte - #0 b31b30b29b28b27b26b25b24
>
> Byte - #1 b23b22b21b20b19b18b17b16
>
> Byte - #2 b15b14b13b12b11b10b09b08
>
> Byte - #3 b07b06b05b04b03b02b01b00

Do not make sense to me.  The first line #0 has 8 bytes in it.  I did some searching and this is a better explanation (http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~ich/classes/mumt306/midiformat.pdf).  Taking the contents from page 2 and editing them for clarity.

```
 Offset           | Byte 0 | Byte 1 | Byte 2 |  Byte 3
 --------   bits  |  24-31 | 16-23  |  8-15  |   0-7
 00000000         |    00  |        |        |
 00000040         |    40  |        |        |
 0000007F         |    7F  |        |        |
 00000080         |    81  |   00   |        |
 00002000         |    C0  |   00   |        |
 00003FFF         |    FF  |   7F   |        |             <--- example
 00004000         |    81  |   80   |   00   |
 00100000         |    C0  |   80   |   00   |
 001FFFFF         |    FF  |   FF   |   7F   |
 00200000         |    81  |   80   |   80   |   00
 08000000         |    C0  |   80   |   80   |   00
 0FFFFFFF         |    FF  |   FF   |   FF   |   7F


Example at offset 3FFF
Hex format 0xFF7F_0000 (32-bit number, unused bits are 0) 

31 30 29 28 27 26 25 24 23 22 21 20 19 18 17 16
 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1

15 14 13 12 11 10 09 08 07 06 05 04 03 02 01 00
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Does this help?

Comment: This doesn’t address the question. The issue is that MIDI data bytes must have a zero in the MSB. The question is about how to do that.